# '+[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10b546238'

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard, objective-c-category

I have a UIStoryboard extension that initiates a storyboard based of the type/name passed in. I
'm using +[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:] to create the storyboard but it seems that Objc can't find the selector for it.

```
#define valueString(enum) [@[@"Main",@"Login"] objectAtIndex:enum]

@interface UIStoryboard (Utility)

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, StoryboardType) {
    StoryboardTypeMain,
    StoryboardTypeLogin
};

- (instancetype) initWithType:(StoryboardType)type bundle:    (NSBundle*)bundle;
- (instancetype) initWithType:(StoryboardType)type;

@implementation

- (instancetype)initWithType:(StoryboardType)type bundle:(NSBundle *)bundle {
    self = [[self class] storyboardWithName:valueString(type) bundle:bundle];
    return self;

}


- (instancetype)initWithType:(StoryboardType)type {
    self = [[self class] storyboardWithName:valueString(type) bundle:nil];
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it worked. How are you calling your methods? Are you sure that whatever you call your `- (instancetype)initWithType:(StoryboardType)type ` on is an instance of UIStoryboard? PS. Your init method creates another object, then calls another method on it that returns result of a class method, thus wasting two allocations. Why?

Comment: Thinking back on common mistakes with categories - make sure that your file is added to your target.

Comment: storyboard = [[UIStoryboard alloc] initWithType:StoryboardTypeLogin bundle:nil]; This is how I'm calling it in my AppDelegate.

Comment: I checked in the debugger and self is an instance of UIStoryboard